# Phonegap nav module not loading with JQM

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to load in GPS co-ords in my JQM / Phonegap app - the first alert of trying hits but the rest fails with no errors that I can see. Doesn't hit the onsucess or onerror as far as i can tell.

```
if (pageId === 'latlong') {

        console.log("Nooooooops");
        alert("trying");
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
        function onSuccess(position) {
            localStorage.set("Lat", position.coords.latitude);
            localStorage.set("Long", position.coords.longitude);

            alert(localStorage.getItem("Lat"));
            alert(localStorage.getItem("Long"));
        };

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        $("#latlongLat").append(localStorage.get("Lat"));
        $("#latlongLong").append(localStorage.get("Long"));

    }
```

I'm trying this on the AVD and Samsung Galaxy s4 but no luck.

Comment: Have you installed Phonegap geolocation plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Ah Samsung Galaxy series, it simply don't like Phonegap/Cordova geolocation.

From my experience you will need to set additional options, like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{
    enableHighAccuracy : true,
    maximumAge : 3000,
    timeout : 60000
});
```

First try playing with **enableHighAccuracy** true or false, my old S3 only worked when it was set to true. Give it a reasonable timeout, again Samsung Galaxy series has a rather flunky GPS.

On the other side timeout is requires when testing on AVD, plus some times **enableHighAccuracy** needs to be set to false (AVD only).

Plus, don't forget to install plugin, a lot of people don't know that as of version 3.0, Phonegap/Cordova implements device-level APIs as plugins.

Comment: Thanks for that, I added the line to the config of phonegap to enable GPS - that's all I need to add yeah? (still having issues)

Comment: The problem i'm getting is i'm getting nothing no error (finding it really hard to debug!)

Comment: What phonegap versio are you using and if it's higher then 2.9 did you install plugin? Default gps support is browser related, basically Phonegap can prevent you from using this functionality. Plus have you tried setting high accurity?